# Delete item using redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am trying to get my head around Redux. Doing something like TODO APP with React and Redux. I can add a new task, update its value, but I cannot delete the item correctly. I get an error `Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): Cannot read property 'id' of undefined` all the time. I pass the ID to the Delete function just like I do in the Update function. Server side works well. The `fetch` function itself works, and the delete of item from the database works, but an error occurs on the client side Help please guys

```
const initialState = {
  list: [],
}

export default (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case GET_TASKS: {
      return { ...state, list: action.tasks }
    }
    case CREATE_TASK: {
      return { ...state, list: [...state.list, action.task] }
    }
    case UPDATE_STATUS: {
      return {
        ...state,
        list: state.list.map((it) => {
          return action.task.id === it.id ? action.task : it
        }),
      }
    }
    case DELETE_TASK: {
      return {
        list: state.list.map((it) => {
          return action.task.id !== it.id ? action.task : it
        }),
      }
    }

    default:
      return state
  }
}

export function getTasks() {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch("/api/task")
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then(({ data: tasks }) => {
        dispatch({ type: GET_TASKS, tasks })
      })
  }
}

export function deleteTask(id) {
  return (dispatch) => {
    fetch(`/api/v1/task/${id}`, {
      method: "DELETE",
    })
      .then((r) => r.json())
      .then(({ data: task }) => {
        dispatch({ type: DELETE_TASK, task })
      })
  }
}
```

Comment: Could you provide codesandbox to test it? Try Instead of use `state.list.map` in `DELETE`, use `state.list.filter(it => it.id !== action.task.id)` and check it. If not, provide us codesandbox

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My first question would be, in your `deleteTask` method what is being returned here? Does a delete method actually return the task you deleted?

```
.then(({ data: task }) => {
    dispatch({ type: DELETE_TASK, task })
}
```

If not, another way you can address this is by changing the `task` in your dispatch to the `id` you are passing to the `deleteTask` method:

```
dispatch({ type: DELETE_TASK, id });
```

Then use the filter method instead of map in your reducer to return the tasks that don't match that deleted task's id, effectively "deleting" it from your state:

```
case DELETE_TASK: {
  return {
     list: state.list.filter((it) => {
         return action.id !== it.id;
     }),
  }
}
```